# MYSQL SUM or Combine one column when two columns match

Tags: mysql

I tried and tried but I am just not getting it.

What I am try to do is this.  I have one table and when there are matching productCode's with matching productPrice's, I need the results to combine the matching productCodes, sum the productUnits of the matching productCode's then multiply them by the productPrice.

- note      :   these have matching prices and productcode.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjCEZ.png)

I attached a picture of my example because I suck at HTML formatting also.

Comment: where does product code 102 come from in results table in your picture? did you mistake something in the above table?

Comment: how come you reach that total like for example 0101 total of 2400?

Comment: Why the downvote? He's a new user and could probably benefit from the question being edited a bit, and sure there's a small issue with his result set, but @Barmar was able to answer the (rather obvious SUM / GROUP BY) question

Comment: @e_i_pi I didn't downvote, but probably it was for not showing any effort to solve it.

Comment: Dipu, that was 102 was a typo. I editied it. Thanks.

Comment: hey guys.  a bit of a question here as a newbie.  as a end user of stackflow my preference is to see short (if possible), clean and concise questions. Seeing what someone's broken code looks like doesn't help me normally.  Should I make a point next time to show my attempts/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with multiple columns, to combine all the rows where those columns match. Then just sum the `productUnits` in those rows.

```
SELECT productCode, productPrice, SUM(productUnits) AS productUnits, productPrice * SUM(productUnits) AS totals
FROM orders_products
GROUP BY productCode, productPrice
```